# The request is delayed until it reaches the middleware

Tags: python, django, datadog

[image: Datadog Trace]

I am using the Django Framework, and every time I deploy to production, there's a temporary delay of requests before they reach the middleware. What can I check to identify the cause of this issue?

Comment: Do you have custom middlware? , show us the code for middlware + view + urls for a specific delaying url.

Comment: @Pycm
The First of middlewares is HealthCheckMiddleware. And Here is code

https://gist.github.com/ryandev421/3e99d5a3d86410ae8722d6fe0283f361

Comment: HealthCheckMiddleware seems ok. It may be another problem. View ? Tell us about your environment, how do you access the site?

Comment: How do you expect us to give an answer without you telling us what is your vehicle, bus, car, or train? and Engin details?  You just show us a picture of a side mirror and expect us to understand your problem and fix it.